# Which cruisers can stealthily torpedo?

Tags: world-of-warships

Which CAs can "stealth-torp"? "stealth-torp" means detectability range  < torpedo range.

I'm asking just for CAs, not DDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [world of warships forum](https://forum.worldofwarships.com/topic/119909-how-to-play-good-torpedo-cruisers/) cruisers that can "stealth-torp" are: Atago, Edinburgh, Minotaur, Iwaki Alpha.